# Fixed length line segment in QGIS: why does helping circle not appear always?

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I am working with fixed line lengths. Advanced Digitizing Panel is activated and I set the line length. Usually there is a the blue "helping" circle whose radius is the value entered in the distance text box (see picture).

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQLvb.jpg]

But sometimes there is no circle. **Why is that?**

I would like to always see the blue circle.

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting enter after you type out the length